# Слетел перевод в очереди первых сообщений (вопросов/ответов)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, первые-ответы

Слетел перевод в очереди первых сообщений (вопросов/ответов). Вот скриншот:

> [image: слетел перевод в очереди первых сообщений]

Comment: интересно за что минус?

Comment: @Danis может кто-то не понял, о чем речь, или палец дрогнул, или просто ненавистник.

Comment: @Danis минусатор хочет, чтобы всё было на английском =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17997

Будет в новых сборках, текущая 2023.3.17.43323